# "Модные глаголы"

Tags: глаголы, склонение, орфография

Мой сын меня совсем запутал с этими  - "ложить" и "звонить"! Какая то мода пошла выпендриваться насчёт этих глаголов. ПРОСВЕТИТЕ! Но по-проще пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

А в чём "выпендрёж"? Почему не употребляется глагол ЛОЖИТЬ без приставки и постфикса?

Из общелитературного употребления вышел в 19 веке, потому что совпал с французским словом, имеющим фривольный смысл("ложить на ложе"), а в просторечии, среди простого народа, не знающего французского языка, осталось. Но культурный человек избегает таких слов.Нет слова лОжит в словаре культурного человека.

ЗвонИть, звонИт, звонЯт - нормативное ударение русского глагола - мерило уровня речевой культуры, потому что звОнит-просторечное ударение, возможное для групп людей с низким уровнем культуры. Видимо, сын заставляет Вас говорить культурно?

Comment: Смотри, как французы нам подгадили! Нормальный глагол *ложИть* вывели из употребления. Надо поискать еще каких нехороших совпадений в разных европейских языках и сотню-другую русских слов запретить. Мультикультурное взаимодействие, во как.